# jQuery How to Make $(this) Selector Fires Multiple Classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-selectors

I have 2 tables with different class that have same contain.
Table 1 shown in main section and the second table shown on a popup function. Both table still on the same page html.

I have a click function using **2 classes selectors** which is I hope can fires both tables on single click and change both tables contain. But the click function only works in one table, not both tables.

Note that the second table is dinamically created and not always existed.

How to make it fires both tables on each click and not return error if second table doesn't exist.

My code:

```js
$('.table1 a.name, .table2 a.name').click(function(c){
 c.preventDefault();
 var $item = $(this); 
 var checked = $('<img class="checked" src="https://findicons.com/files/icons/1964/colorcons_green/128/checkmark.png" width="30" height="30">');
  //$.post("", {data:datas},function(data){
    // some ajax result
    $($item).before(checked);
    $('img.checked').not(checked).remove();
  //});
});
```

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Table 1</h2>

<table class="table1">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="name" href="https://stackoverflow.com">Alfreds Futterkiste</a></td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="name" href="https://stackoverflow.com/2">Centro comercial Moctezuma</a></td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="name" href="https://stackoverflow.com/3">Ernst Handel</a></td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br>

<h2>Table 2</h2>

<table class="table2">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="name" href="https://stackoverflow.com">Alfreds Futterkiste</a></td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="name" href="https://stackoverflow.com/2">Centro comercial Moctezuma</a></td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="name" href="https://stackoverflow.com/3">Ernst Handel</a></td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for this post.

The problem is in jQuery the function `this` on click function only refer to the element 
that got clicked. It's never counted on other elements which is declared as selectors even if they have identical contents.

So the solution if you have same content in multiple elements is to use `filter` function to search for same values and then you can threated them all as one in your action.

In my case I just need to marked the same `a href` values in all elements.

The updated snippet

```js
$('.table1 a.name, .table2 a.name').click(function(c){
 c.preventDefault();
 var $item = $(this).attr('href'); 
 var checked = $('<img class="checked" src="https://findicons.com/files/icons/1964/colorcons_green/128/checkmark.png" width="30" height="30">');
  //$.post("", {data:datas},function(data){
    // some ajax result
    //$($item).before(checked);
    
    var marked =  $('.table1 a.name, .table2 a.name').filter(function() {
       $('img.checked').not(marked).remove();
        return $(this).attr('href') ===  $item;
    }).before(checked);   
    
    
  //});
});
```

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Table 1</h2>

<table class="table1">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="name" href="https://stackoverflow.com">Alfreds Futterkiste</a></td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="name" href="https://stackoverflow.com/2">Centro comercial Moctezuma</a></td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="name" href="https://stackoverflow.com/3">Ernst Handel</a></td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h2>Table 2</h2>

<table class="table2">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="name" href="https://stackoverflow.com">Alfreds Futterkiste</a></td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="name" href="https://stackoverflow.com/2">Centro comercial Moctezuma</a></td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a class="name" href="https://stackoverflow.com/3">Ernst Handel</a></td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

From this- 
[Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

`on` function in jQuery can attach event to already created elements only directly.

For example, you can use following code for dynamically created `table2`-

```
$('body').on('click', '.table2 a.name', function (event){
//Code here
});
```

When there is a click on the `body`, check if target is `.table2 a.name`, if yes, execute the function.

Comment: With `$(this)` selector I can execute the dinamically created table 2 properly. No problem there. The issue here is it can't executed both tables at once. I think there's still incorrect syntax with this combined selector `$('.table1 a.name, .table2 a.name')` cause it only can execute one table at a time.

Comment: @DrunkenM, Use `$(document).on('click', '.table1 a.name, .table2 a.name', function(){ //Your code})`

Comment: @Satpal Still not working. It is not executing both tables. http://jsfiddle.net/2rt2t/342/

Comment: @Satpal I found a workaround using a `filter function`. Do you still want to answer this question? Please remove the duplicate as the reference link doesn't  show the right solution to this question.